# I/O operation on closed file when saving a model

Tags: python, django, file

Hi guys i have my problem in this part in the code. I have multiple files uploaded from o global variable.

```
file_car = None # Global variable
```

and in my views.py

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
         if file_car is None:
         print request.FILES
         file_car = [request.FILES.get('dzfile[%d]' % i)
         for i in range(0, len(request.FILES))]
```

I need to use like this because I need to use this images in a lot of other views. But the problem is when I want to save

```
 for f in file_car:
            print f
            myfyle= File(f)
            #myfyle.open()
            aux = Attachment()
            aux.name= f
            aux.car = car
            aux.save() # here is the error. I tried opening the file but it said you cannot reopen the file
```

It throw me I/O operation on closed file.I'm going crazy with this. Sorry for my bad english

Edit Here is a more compressive code if it helps

```
 from django.core.files import File
def createCarView(request):
        global file_car
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            if file_car is None:
                form = CarForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # other valus
                print request.FILES # Print all the file that I get
                file_car = [request.FILES.get('dzfile[%d]' % i)
                    for i in range(0, len(request.FILES))] # Have all the fileS!
                if form.is_valid():
                            # omitted all the other part of the form!    
                            car.save()  
                            for f in file_car:
                              print f
                              #myfyle.open()
                              aux = Attachment()
                              aux.name=myfyle
                              aux.car = car
                              aux.save() #Error in here
                              print aux.name
                              file_car=None # cleaning the global var     
                              return HttpResponseRedirect('/car/create')
```

models.py

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.FileField(_('File'),
        upload_to=upload_to_get,
        )
```

Comment: Which line gets the I/O error?

Comment: The aux.save throw me the error

Comment: What are the `File` and `Attachment` classes?

Comment: Added the edit if it code is more compressive

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Code is not clear but error says you should open the file so how about trying something like this ? :

```
 for f in file_car:
     with open(f,"a") as f:
         print f
         myfyle= File(f)
         aux = Attachment()
         aux.name=myfyle
         aux.car = car
         aux.save()
```

Comment: Tried already that it Throw me this error coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found